How do I train a model in Tensorflow that captures Joint Class Dependencies?
I've been doing some modeling of fantasy points for baseball players as a hobby. For a given team in a given game, there are nine (9) starting batters who bat in order.
I've trained each of their point distributions as a multi-class classifier (with weighted label smoothing) to determine each of their likelihoods of earning x discrete points in a given game, with some success. This gives me access to the percentile that each player reached in a given game.
What I'd like to do is train a model that captures the dependency between players. I've tried just fitting an empirical copula, but noticed that the dependency varies by game environment (i.e., two players are likelier to simultaneously have high-tail outcomes in a high-total game than a low-total game).
Ideally, a solution would look something like this:
batter1_percentiles = [0.11,0.43,0.67,0.51 , ... , 0.33]

...

batter9_percentiles = [0.27,0.68,0.44,0.97 , ... , 0.12]

model = tf_keras.sequential([
    tf_keras.layers.Dense(10),
    tf_keras.layers.Dense(5),
    # Something here
    ])

model.compile(#some stuff)
model.fit(#some stuff)
joint_percentiles = model(x_tst) #this could return the percentile outcome of each class
# or a class prediction for each class, I have no particular preference

#Calling model(x_tst) again should return different percentiles or class predictions, such
#that if I call it many times, I receive the joint probability distribution of the players
#in each game



You might look up "item-response theory" as a model class which separates the "difficulty" of test questions from the "competency" of the test takers. Related work has been done for "teacher value-added" models in education.
More concretely, you might consider a hierarchical model using tfd.JointDistributionCoroutine which samples a inverse_pitcher_skill from tfd.Gamma, then samples player hit counts from tfd.Poisson(inverse_pitcher_skill + player_skill).

The thing to consider is that the points distribution also depends on, say, runs batted in, so batter 2 and batter 1 have correlated outcomes. Ultimately, what I'm looking for is essentially a trainable 9-dimensional KDE
